# Story where man develops a virtual reality world or game

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds

In the early to mid 90's I read a book I really enjoyed and I haven't been able to find it. I thought it was called ' Network'. The story surrounded a man that was developing a virtual reality world or game and gets into trouble and has to go on the run. Somewhere in the mix a company called 'Kyocera-Merck' that is manipulating things. He ends up with a girl that is helping him and seek the help of a 'slash boxer' that is also an attorney and counsels them. They are eventually caught trying to break in and are dumped into the virtual reality land and the vr suits allow them to feel pain and temperature and inflicts damage if they are hurt in the vr world. I tried to find this book but I may be way off with the title but that's what I remember. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't find any mentions of virtual reality, but a company by that name shows up in *Hot Sky at Midnight* by Robert Silverberg as per https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1538483.Hot_Sky_at_Midnight

Comment: I actually just ran across this one and I am not too sure. Isn't the main character blind? I will have to look into that one again.